# Как сравнить даты

Tags: c#, дата, datetime

Есть заранее известная дата.  Например, есть некий документ от 01.03.2018, действителен до 01.05.2018. И есть текущая дата. Как можно проверить осталось ли меньше месяца до 01.05.2018 или больше месяца? Никак не соображу как это можно проверить.

Comment: `bool enougthTime = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1) <= new DateTime(2018, 5, 1);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добавьте к сегодняшней дате один месяц и сравните получившийся результат с нужной датой. Добавить месяц можно с помощью метода [`AddMonth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var date = new DateTime(2018, 5, 1);
if (DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1) > date)
    Console.WriteLine("Меньше месяца");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Больше месяца");
```

Это же условие можно переписать по другому, если вам это более понятно (если дата окончания минус 1 месяц уже прошла, то осталось меньше месяца):

```
if (DateTime.Today > date.AddMonths(-1)) ...
```

Ну и имейте ввиду, что обычно юристы устанавливают всевозможные сроки в сутках, т. к. месяцы в году имеют разную продолжительность, поэтому, возможно, правильнее будет использовать метод `AddDays`, например:

```
if (DateTime.Today.AddDays(30) > date) ...
```

или, то же самое:

```
if ((date - DateTime.Today).TotalDays < 30) ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как раз то что нужно. Ну тут не для юристов, просто небольшая проверка.

Comment: Еще можно использовать метод, контролирующий время до секунды DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(4, 2, 10)); Добавляет 4 дня, 2 часа и 10 минут

Comment: @ВасилийМ, можно тогда уж использовать и перегруженные операции `+/-`, типа `(DateTime.Today - date).TotalDays > 30`